# Exit/Nonexit probabilities of Two Correlated Brownian Motions

Tags: probability, statistics, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

Given two correlated Brownian Motions $X, Y$ starting at $0$ with correlation $\rho$ and respective drifts and variances $\mu_X, \mu_Y, \sigma_X^2, \sigma_Y^2$, define moving-maxima $X^*_t$ and $Y^*_t$ as
$$X^*_t=\max_{0\le s\le t}X_s.$$
Find the probability
$$\mathbb{P}(X^*_t<a, Y^*_t>b)$$ for $a,b,t>0$.

Does anyone know how to solve this or have suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

see the work in [Exact asymptotics of component-wise extrema of two-dimensional Brownian motion](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10687-020-00387-y)

at least for the tail behaviour.